# Getting error when trying to start ember server

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, ember-cli

I am trying to start my server from within my app using the command;

> ember serve

However I get a no such file or directory error as below;

```
version: 1.13.8
Livereload server on http://localhost:49156
Serving on http://localhost:4200/
ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\MyApp\mycode\tmp\concat_with_maps-input_base_path-tfPGUnEW.tmp\0\bower_components\ember-template-compiler\index.js'
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\MyApp\mycode\tmp\concat_with_maps-input_base_path-tfPGUnEW.tmp\0\bower_components\ember-template-compiler\index.js'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:797:18)
    at ConcatWithMaps.keyForFile (C:\MyApp\mycode\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\broccoli-sourcemap-concat\node_modules\broccoli-caching-writer\index.js:91:55)
    at Array.map (native)
    at ConcatWithMaps.CachingWriter._conditionalBuild (C:\MyApp\mycode\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\broccoli-sourcemap-concat\node_modules\broccoli-caching-writer\index.js:107:61)
    at C:\MyApp\mycode\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\broccoli-sourcemap-concat\node_modules\broccoli-caching-writer\node_modules\broccoli-plugin\read_compat.js:61:34
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (C:\MyApp\mycode\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:493:16)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (C:\MyApp\mycode\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:505:17)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$publish (C:\MyApp\mycode\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:476:11)
    at lib$rsvp$asap$$flush (C:\MyApp\mycode\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1198:9)
```

Where should I look to fix the issue?

Comment: have you run through the commands `npm install; bower install; ember build;`?

Comment: i have run npm install, then bower install (but not ember build) ...i m really new to ember...so not really know if ember build is also necessary ? pls let me know

Comment: It shouldnt be, but... is `ember-template-compiler` installed?

Comment: where should i look for it exactly ? considering my new project is in C:\MyApp\mycode\

Comment: also doing ember build gives the same error

Comment: it should be in your package.json file

Comment: I do not see ember-template-compiler in my package.json (i.e. under C:\MyApp\mycode )

Comment: try adding it to your `package.json` and then run `npm install` again.

Comment: Ok...Trying with "dependencies" as 
    "ember-template-compiler": "http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.13.3/ember-template-compiler.js"

Comment: It says npm ERR! not a package C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-14092-b2803cbc\builds.emberjs.com\tags\v1.13.3\ember-template-compiler.js

Comment: This is when I do npm install

Comment: your `package.json` should have something like `"ember-template-compiler": "1.9.0"` or alternatively you can run `npm install ember-template-compiler --save` which will install it and save it to your package.json

Comment: Tried doing the above...still get the same error....No such file or dir

Comment: Not sure if it is trying to look under bower and we are doing for npm (just a wild guess!)

Comment: what version of ember are you using? and are you using ember-cli?

Comment: My ember version is 1.13.1 (and am also using ember-cli)

Comment: Sorry man. Im out of ideas. :(

Comment: but u think the issue seems to be mostly related to ember-template-compiler dependency issue ?

Comment: Share your package.json and bower.json.

Comment: @testndtv, These weird errors happens when NPM/Bower tries to load 2 different versions of the same package (It's difficult to debug though). Every time if you face issues related to node or bower components, then you have clean the node and bower cache and try to install it again. Follow the below steps: 1. Delete node_modules folder. 2. `npm cache clean`. 3. npm install. 4. Delete bower_components folder. 5. `bower cache clean`. 6. bower install. Let me know if this works. Thanks

Comment: Thx a lot...While I try to do these steps...which node_modules folder are you asking me to delete ? Is the one immediately under C:\MyCode\myapp

Comment: Tried the above...still getting the same error...it is throwing file not found one by one (as i add the ones it shows) for different dependencies !

Comment: @testndtv Did you ever get this sorted out? I'm getting the same error with 1.13.8. Had you installed any addons? Or is this happening with a fresh install?

Comment: Got this sorted by having the tmp directory out of the Sublime Text Editor which I was using...